# Sending emails using smtp with TLS/SSL from ActionScript3/Adobe AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I am trying to send emails using smtp in an Adobe AIR application, I am unable to make the code work with gmail but it works with my hosted email without TLS/SSL so my assumption is that TLS/SSL is the issue.
I am using SMTPMAiller from http://www.bytearray.org/?p=27
with latest as3cryptolib I can fine.
I do not want to use a server side script.
Please respond only if you have a working code/application that works with gmail in present.
Thank you

Edit: My question is if you have already this working in present what libraries and what versions are you using, I am sure my libraries are too old.

Comment: That last sentence is not how S.O works. Imagine I have a GMail account (true) and 30 mins spare (maybe), if you post debuggable code we could both learn something new towards a result, isn't it?... Anyways see if these [**search results**](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=smpt+gmail) have any hints that could be applied to your AIR code. Also if open to alternative mailer for GMail this [**comment sounds promising**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391782/using-smtp-mailer-but-not-successful-yet#comment12302099_9391782) (see both comment links since demo codes are for GMail)

Comment: @VC.One I can post my code and mayber a test project but I do not expect that someone would debug my code, the answer I expect is something like "I have an app that does this in present and I am using library X",. The lib I use worked before but things changed in last 5 years but the libraries and AIR stagnated.

Comment: Library age ain't nothing but a number, the problem/solution remains same. The problem is SMTP Mailer doesn't handle SSL (see the comments in that forum, just word search "ssl" and ppl are asking for it). Did you try the links shown in my other comment? Takes you to [**AirxMail**](http://flex.coltware.com/as3-flex-air/airxmail/) as designed to solve the SSL issue. You could test their sample code (for GMail) while you wait for Answer from here...

Comment: @VC.OneI tried that library too recently, It did not work, I get timeouts issue, it can't connect, also the comments are in chinese or a similar language so it was hard to understand some parts in the code(code is in english though). Thanks you for your answer, probably my only solution would be to try to check the network traffic and maybe find the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to send emails from gmail.yahoo using SMTP and SSL using this library [airxmail](https://github.com/coltware/airxmail)
I had a few problems though, I was trying to log the code using event listeners to understand what is going wrong but adding a specific listener caused problems, I reported it [here](https://github.com/coltware/airxmail/issues/18) . For logging I suggest using what the author recommends(the mx.Log).
Other issue was caused by the not clear documentation from the first example I found, there was some code that needed to run for SSL only and other code that needed to run for TLS only.

I did not had time or need to test TLS so I am not sure if it works, code is not yet in production so maybe I will find more issues later.

I created a wrapper class, my needs is to have a test function when a user will add his email credentials and settings, then have the ability to send more then one email,  I will show my main code here , use at your own risk.

I tried adding my sample here but SO code formatted did not like it, [here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/simion314/b9ca4c8aefee03002dcd7029068106c5#file-airxmailex-as) I hope it will help.

Comment: Also make sure you set option "Allow less secure apps" to ON in your gmail account. Otherwise you can't authenticate.